# Scraping attempt using CasperJS , PhantomJS, and a postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, phantomjs, casperjs

I am attempting to scrape a site which uses .aspx files, or ASP.net .  There are radio buttons which on each click, perform a postback.

I'm now aware that a postback in ASP.net is merely a POST call, but does anyone know what is involved with setting up this POST within either CasperJS or PhantomJS?

I imagine it's something like this however I am missing the POST to replicate the callback..  Anyone had to do this and could provide some insight would be appreciated.

```
casper.start('target.aspx',function() {
    this.capture('Step1.png');
    this.test.assertExists('#ctl00_cphMainContent_ucUnifiedSearch_rdoOrg', 'PASS');
    this.click('input[name="ctl00$cphMainContent$ucUnifiedSearch$rdoSearchBy"][value="rdoOrg"]');    
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('finished');
    this.capture('Step2.png');  
});
```

The specific target input tag & postback are :

```
<input id="ctl00_cphMainContent_ucUnifiedSearch_rdoOrg" type="radio" name="ctl00$cphMainContent$ucUnifiedSearch$rdoSearchBy" value="rdoOrg" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cphMainContent$ucUnifiedSearch$rdoOrg\',\'\')', 0)">
```

Comment: I'm missing the question. what does your script lack? you do click the button. you need to listen for the post being sent? for the serve response? for some gui change? something else?

Comment: Greetings, I've since moved around this problem.. but essentially it can be replicated by attempting to click a button on THIS site in casper JS..

http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/Search/iapd_Search.aspx

I cannot replicate the click without the proper POST callback.. wondering if it can be done in CasperJS or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the page does a POST call to the page. This is done through javascript which is not picked up by casperjs as a transition to the next page. Because of this the last step (`run`) does not wait for the page reload. You need to wait for the page transition yourself.

You can do this by waiting for a specific field that exists only in the reloaded page. In your case this will be

```
casper.waitForSelector('#ctl00_cphMainContent_ucUnifiedSearch_txtFirm');
```

So the resulting script is

```
casper.start('http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/Search/iapd_Search.aspx', function() {
    this.capture('Step1.png');
    this.click('input[name="ctl00$cphMainContent$ucUnifiedSearch$rdoSearchBy"][value="rdoOrg"]');    
});

casper.waitForSelector('#ctl00_cphMainContent_ucUnifiedSearch_txtFirm');

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('finished');
    this.capture('Step2.png');  
});
```